# "ImportError: No module named urls" while following Django Tutorial

Tags: python, django

I am following the official django tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial04/

I am using Django 1.9.8 and I am now getting the following error in `/polls/views.py`:

```
File "C:\Users\hk\Documents\mysite\polls\views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.urls import reverse
ImportError: No module named urls
```

**polls/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Choice, Question
# ...
```

**mysite/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns=[
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]
```

**mysite/mysite/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That tutorial requires Django 1.10 while you seem to be using an older version. In this case, you should import `reverse` as follows:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
```

To upgrade your Django version, use the following command (in your command line, *not* in the Python shell):

```
pip install --upgrade django
```

Answer (score 1):

Latest tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) uses  `Django 2.0, which supports Python 3.4 and later`

Since I ran into this same issue I had to upgrade by python as well as django

```
sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
pip3 install --upgrade django
```

to see your django version run following command -

```
python3 -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
```

for me it says `2.0.1`

To check python version run -

```
python3 --version
```

For me it is `Python 3.5.2`

Answer (score -1):

At times, if one has multiple copies of django running on one's machine like I had, if the current project requires a different version of sjango, it is easier to simply go to `preferences -> project interpreter -> add a virtual env -> install latest copy of django`.
Now pycharm will interpret the project correctly.

Comment: The OP doesn't specify they are using pycharm.